# How can I create a task that sets environment variables then runs another task?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a task(named "run"). I would like to create a task called "runDev" that configures environment variables and then calls "run". I'm unsure currently how to do this after some research.

I have tried using the following:

```
tasks.register("runDev", JavaExec::class) {
    environment("server_env", "dev")
    finalizedBy("run")
}
```

But Gradle tells me runDev failed after trying to run it